# Very Strange Characterisation of Topology

Tags: general-topology

[Definition of Topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Characterizations_of_the_category_of_topological_spaces&oldid=520787219#Definition_of_a_Topology)

I don't understand this characterisation of a topology, I don't even comprehend what $g\colon\{ \{\{\}\},\{\{\},\{\{\}\}\}\} \rightarrow T$ should mean? Can somebody explain it to me?

Comment: If I read $\{\} = \varnothing = 0$ (as an ordinal), then it appears that the domain of $g$ is the Kuratowski ordered pair $(1,0)$, which equals the set $\{1, 2\}$. I don't know what it's supposed to mean, though.

Comment: A true masterpiece of obfuscation :-)

Comment: I think you should be glad you don't understand it. Otherwise it would mean you have a mind like the person that wrote that definition down!

Comment: This is just the kind of silliness that gives mathematics a bad rep!

Answer (score 11):

It is just an attempt to express the usual axioms of topology in a more "formal" manner. Like [Lord_Farin wrote](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/43351/lord-farin), we can write the sets $\mathbf{0} = \emptyset = \{\}$, $\mathbf{1} = \{\mathbf{0}\} = \{\{\}\}$, and $\mathbf{2} = \{\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{1}\} = \{\{\}, \{\{\}\}\}$ using [von Neumann's notation for integers](http://planetmath.org/VonNeumannInteger.html). Then the domain of $g$ is just the two-point set $\{ \mathbf{1}, \mathbf{2}\}$.

---

Now, $f:I \to T$ means that for each $i\in I$ we have $(i)f \in T$ is an element of the topology (here we follow the Wikipedia article to act functions on the right instead of on the left as usual). So $\cup_{I}(i)f \in T$ for any set $I$ and any function $f:I \to T$ is just a way to say, in notations, that "$T$ is closed under arbitrary union."

On the other hand interpreting $g: \{\mathbf{1},\mathbf{2}\} \to T$ and $(\mathbf{1})g \cap (\mathbf{2})g \in T$ just say, in notations, that "$T$ is closed under pairwise intersections".

Comment: Ah of course, that makes sense. However, we will probably never know why the postfix notation is used, and why not e.g. $\mathbf 0$ and $\mathbf 1$ are used in place of $\mathbf 1$ and $\mathbf 2$. Let alone the notation $\varnothing$... This way it's just needlessly confusing.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I think we can make an educated guess about the "why" from the Wikipedia history.  See upcoming answer.

Comment: In view of [Erick's sleuthing](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/302153/1543), the OP (at Wikipedia) may have had in mind not von Neumann's notation, but that which was used in Morse-Kelley set theory. `:-)`

Comment: Somebody removed the definition from Wikipedia. Maybe one should reproduce it here?

Comment: @Martin: the good thing about Wikipedia (which we reproduce here) is that all edits can be tracked in histories. So I've edited the OP to replace the link with one to a version where the definition stood.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit hard to read when formatted as a comment, but here is the "motivation" in the words of the [Wikipedia user](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Characterizations_of_the_category_of_topological_spaces&action=history) who made that particular edit in October 2012.

Originally the definition was short and plain.  Perhaps a bit quaint in the use of postfix, and subpar grammar and typography, but it isn't hard to piece together.  The idea is to define a topology in terms of $T$ first rather than as a collection of subsets of $X$, which is not an unreasonable idea.

> A topology is a set $T$ such that
>
> 1. For all set $I$.For all function $f:I\to T$ $\cup(i)f \in T$.
> 2. For all function $f:\{1,2\} \to T$ $(1)f\cap(2)f \in T$.

This was subsequently deleted by another user who described it as "an attempt to define $T$ as set of open sets in a most unreadable manner."  The previous user then restored the content, adding the following message:

> Hello,
>
> First of all I want to say that the definition of a "topology" rather
>   than a Topological space is standard (ie Kelley General Topology) The
>   definition is correct and you can easily prove it The notation (a)f
>   instead of f(a) is standard too and, imo, it emphasises the formal
>   idea of a function, so to say (a)f is to say a in pi_1(f) where
>   f:=(A,f,B) so, for example, b=(a)f is to say (a,b) in f. i corrected
>   and supress the use of the non-necessary symbols 1,2

The current revision would appear to be merely a sarcastic response (temper tantrum?) to the criticism.  The part that convinces me is how thoroughly he/she eliminated the use of "non-necessary" symbols 1,2, even from the enumerate list!

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply. It makes sense now. It is yet another example of the (un)reliability (mathematical) WP that this monstrosity has resided unchanged since Oct 2012. (IOW: If even this isn't changed, what other grave errors persist?)

Comment: @Lord_Farin: I wouldn't call it a "grave error". The mathematics is (not-so) obviously correct, and the point of view (defining a topology $T$ first then take the space as $\cup T$) is valid. An unfortunate choice of notations it may be, but certainly it is not factually wrong.

Comment: I’m not sure that *correct* makes up for *perversely unreadable*! What on earth was wrong with saying that a topology is a set $\mathscr{T}$ such that for all $\mathscr{U}\subseteq\mathscr{T}$ and all $U,V\in\mathscr{T}$ we have $\bigcup\mathscr{U}\in\mathscr{T}$ and $U\cap V\in\mathscr{U}$?!

Comment: @Willie I'm sorry, my choice of words was bad. My intended reading was: "If this isn't changed, then what other things, possibly grave errors, persist?" It's not what I wrote, but the point stands.

Answer (score 1):

The set $\{0,1\}$ with the Sierpiński topology, which I will call $\rm S$ has the following property : there is a bijection between the topology $\mathcal T$ of any topological space $\rm X$ and the continuous functions $\rm X \to \rm S$.

Comment: True, but is it relevant to the question?